# Is it okay to put baking powder in Yorkshire Pudding batter?

Tags: baking, batter, baking-powder, english-cuisine, yorkshire-puddings

It's just that, the first time I tried, they didn't rise as much as I thought they would. would baking powder help?

Comment: I upvoted the answer below because it is all about the heat, could your oven have been quite cold or opened frequently? I usually preheat the muffin tray with a small amount of vegetable oil in each until it is very hot. Then add the mixture quickly before placing back in the oven. The yorkshires are usually massive.

Answer (score 11):

Yorkshire puddings rise because of the eggs in them. This means that the mixture for you Yorkshire puddings needs **heat** to rise So if your oven is not hot enough, they won't rise as much as you want. So here are some tips:

-make sure your oven is hot before putting your puddings in

-Don't open the oven while cooking your puddings

-I always pre heat the muffin trays before I use them.

So you put your mixture in a hot muffin tray (or something els you use), put the hot muffin tray in a hot oven, and don't open the oven anymore before the cooking time is over. So I won't use baking powder, I first try it by making sure the heat is there.

Note that of course every oven is different and so you might need a couple of time before have the right temperature. Also I recommend this site for more information about Yorkshire puds: http://www.hub-uk.com/tallyrecip03/recipe0124.htm

Comment: It's the tiny trapped air-bubbles in batter that expand exponentially and are locked in by the egg going solid. Very good suggestion here about the heat -expand before getting cooked. Also can look at incorporating more air to start if results still not as wished.

Comment: +1 - hot fat is the absolute no. 1 factor in a well-risen Yorkshire Pudding in my experience. I heat mine for at least half an hour.

Comment: Although this is good information, it really isn't answering the question. There's [already a Q&A about getting Yorkshire Puddings to rise](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/how-do-you-make-yorkshire-puddings-rise-reliably?rq=1), and it already has all of this information. This answer doesn't address whether or not it is appropriate to add baking powder and certainly doesn't explain why, except to dismiss it as "I don't/wouldn't do it".

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would try adding baking powder to see if my usually really good Yorkshire puddings would rise any more but no batter went like light cake mixture was a waste of time will stick with my old recipe. If having trouble add another egg I always use 2 and not the recommended one and they are brilliant. Don't know why I messed around

Answer (score 1):

I use a mix from a cash and carry for yorkshire puddings for my pub sunday lunch service (it's as cheap as buying the ingredients separately), to which you just add water.  It has bicarbonate of soda in it as a raising agent.  The puddings are OK, but not brilliant.  Last week I used my emergency pack of Aunt Bessies mix, and the puds were amazing.  These are the ingredients list:

WHEAT Flour, Dried EGG, Skimmed MILK Powder, Raising Agent (Sodium Bicarbonate), Salt, Sugar, Potato Starch, Emulsifiers (Mono- and Di-glycerides of Fatty Acids, Lacto Glycerides, Propylene Glycol Esters of Fatty Acids), Dried Glucose Syrup, Maltodextrin, Stabiliser (Diphosphates).

So it seems that bicarb is commonly used in prepackaged mixes.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be wild if you made them from eggs, milk and flour.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use baking powder in your mixture. It's an absolute no no, the rise rise LESS and have a cake type texture

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice!  Your answer might be improved by explaining why exactly it's an "absolute no no."  The OP actually implies that he/she wants a greater rise, so simply saying not to use it and that less rise is better doesn't actually address the question.