# Does ingredient order matter when making Yorkshire Puddings?

Tags: yorkshire-puddings

With a mother-in-law who hails from the North of England I am well aware that when I make Yorkshire puddings my method is scrutinized.  Luckily I have been assured by the master of such delights that my method is correct.  First put in the flour, then the egg then the milk - any other way (as in putting the milk before the egg) just does not work!  OK, it may sound silly, but I would never consider doing it any other way.

Can other methods work, or is this the only one which will give good results?

Comment: #rumtscho you have changed the whole ethos of my question by editing it.  The point that I was trying to make is that there are only three ingredients, and a true Northerner would and could not even consider making it any other way, than flour, egg then milk.

Comment: @rumtscho simply changed the wording so that your question would not be subject to closing.

Comment: @dougal you can of course re-edit the question. What I wanted to remove was the question "has anybody else tried it, and what happened", because we don't take this kind of question. If I misunderstood you and you were interested in knowing something other than "do other methods work", you can change it to explain what exactly you wanted to know. Of course, if you were to change it into something that should be closed, we will try to work with you and find a different version, and only close as a last resort.

Comment: OK, I fail to understand what is wrong with my question = @dougal you can of course re-edit the question. What I wanted to remove was the question "has anybody else tried it, and what happened", because we don't take this kind of question."    -    I really want to know, "has anybody else tried it, and what happened?" -  what is wrong with that?

Comment: Asking "has anybody else tried it" isn't constructive. If you spend five minutes reading Yorkie recipes, you'll find dozens of different methods. We're not a chat board and, while personal experience is certainly valuable, the reality is that someone doesn't actually have to have tried it. It is only necessary to know if it is possible, which is what the rephrasing has done. Just because I *personally* haven't tried this method doesn't mean I can't write an answer based on information I find on the web rather than personal experience.

Comment: I don't even see why it's a question. You've been taught a way that works, that you're happy to do, and that your family member nods approvingly at. You presumably enjoy the cooked product. Why do you want to know if the handful of other ways you could do it might work? Why is trying them when you're alone not an option? **Why are you asking?**

Comment: @dougal there is nothing wrong with that, but we don't deal with this type of question. Asking it here is like going to the bakery to buy a frozen cow carcass - you will be asked to go elsewhere with your request. "Has anybody else tried it" is what we call a "poll" question, with one true answer per person answering, but not a single objective answer for everybody. It can be asked on a discussion forum, but it breaks our format and is not accepted here.

Answer (score 4):

People for decades have been convinced that there's one "right" way to make Yorkshire Puddings. The reality is that most if not all of these "tricks" are either unnecessary or outright hurt the outcome.

Kenji over at Serious Eats went a bit bonkers and tried out just about all of the different methods and has summarized it in an [article](http://www.seriouseats.com/2015/12/food-lab-yorkshire-pudding-popover-best-method-science.html) which is paired with his "best Yorkshire puddings" [recipe](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2015/12/the-best-yorkshire-pudding-popover-recipe.html).

While testing the order of adding milk and eggs to flour actually wasn't one of the things he does, the first step of his recipe is to simply mix together the flour, eggs, and milk (plus a tablespoon of water and some salt) - all simultaneously.

> - Combine eggs, flour, milk, water, and salt in a medium bowl and whisk until a smooth batter is formed. Let batter rest at room temperature for at least 30 minutes. Alternatively, for best results, transfer to an airtight container and refrigerate batter overnight or for up to 3 days. Remove from refrigerator while you preheat the oven.

If you're really interested in Yorkies, I strongly suggest you read his article and consider trying the recipe out for yourself. If you want a summary, I've created a shorter version of it in an answer on [this previous question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/65116/33128).

Comment: Being British gives me some insight into how a Yorkshire should look and taste like, certainly no added water, not even a drip.  It would be like me trying to tell a Mexican how to make a Tamale!