# Yorkshire Pudding Batter -- Letting it "Rest"

Tags: yorkshire-puddings

I've heard it's a good idea to let your batter rest overnight.  Since there are eggs in it, I would think that it would have to rest in the refrigerator.  I've also heard that the batter should be at room temperature when you pour it into the pan.  So, should you refrigerate the batter overnight, and then let it sit outside the fridge for a three or four hours to warm it back up to room temperature?

Answer (score 6):

I previously addressed this on a related question [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2582/how-do-you-make-yorkshire-puddings-rise-reliably/65116#65116). I cited Kenji Lopez-Alt's great article about Yorkshire puddings based on his testing a variety of recipes. For the full thing, you can find it on [Serious Eats](http://www.seriouseats.com/2015/12/food-lab-yorkshire-pudding-popover-best-method-science.html). As to resting and batter temperature, this is what he says:

#### Resting Batter:

This was what the tester determined made the largest difference in the quality of the finished product:

> I'm going to say this: **Resting your batter is the single most important step you can take to improving Yorkshire pudding and popovers.** Not only do they come out taller, they also come out much tastier, with a more complex, toasty flavor. Non-rested-batter puddings taste positively flat (literally and figuratively) next to rested-batter puddings.
>
> I'd go so far as to say that resting at least overnight is essential if you are really after the best.

#### Batter temperature:

> - Warmer batter will create taller, crisper puddings with a more hollow core
> - Colder batter will create denser puddings with a more distinct cup.

So, definitely rest your batter (in the fridge!) and pick the batter temperature that matches the outcome you'd prefer.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try putting it in the fridge overnight, and then taking it out in plenty of time to warm up to room temperature.  I always have used room temperature milk and eggs when making it.  That's what my mom did and how I learned to do it.  I wonder if there's even any point to doing that, though, if I'm just going to put it back in the fridge.

Answer (score -1):

I used my batter straight out of the fridge. Hubby said they where the best he’d ever had. I didn’t rest the batter mix. They came out of the oven, light and beautifully risen.  In future I’ll always use thus way. My York Puds where like a pros! Well chuffed.