# Converting between Egg sizes

Tags: eggs, conversion

In the UK eggs are sized as, small, medium, large and extra large.

What weights/ratios do these correspond, so if a recipe calls for 1 large egg, how many small eggs could I use in its place?

I assume that other countries have similar sizing standards, so if we can aggregate non-UK information as well, that'd be a worthwhile addition to the site.

Comment: In the USA I see in stores Medium, Large and Jumbo, not sure if I've seen small or not. I wouldn't be surprised if we don't, we like to have medium sizes with no smalls.... I've seen places where their smallest size is a Large (Large, XL, Super, etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Europe

From [**http://www.egginfo.co.uk/page/eggsizes**](http://www.egginfo.co.uk/page/eggsizes):

```
|-----------------------|
| Size        | Weight  |
|-------------|---------|
| Very large  | >= 73g  |
| Large       | 63-73g  |
| Medium      | 53-63g  |
| Small       | <= 53g  |
|-----------------------|
```

### USA

From [**http://www.georgiaeggs.org/pages/sizeequivalents.html**](http://www.georgiaeggs.org/pages/sizeequivalents.html):

**Size equivalents**

US recipes using eggs, but not specifying size, are referring to large eggs. Here is a substitution table:

```
|------------------------------------------|
| Large | Jumbo | X-Large | Medium | Small |
|-------|-------|---------|--------|-------|
| 1     | 1     | 1       | 1      | 1     |
| 2     | 2     | 2       | 2      | 2     |
| 3     | 3     | 3       | 3      | 4     |
| 4     | 3     | 4       | 5      | 5     |
| 5     | 4     | 4       | 6      | 7     |
| 6     | 5     | 5       | 7      | 8     |
|------------------------------------------|
```

Here is a cup equivalency table as well:

```
|-----------------------------------|
|            TO MAKE 1 CUP          |
|-----------------------------------|
| Egg Size | Whole | Whites | Yolks |
|----------|-------|--------|-------|
| Jumbo    | 4     | 5      | 11    |
| X-Large  | 4     | 6      | 12    |
| Large    | 5     | 7      | 14    |
| Medium   | 5     | 8      | 16    |
| Small    | 6     | 9      | 18    |
|-----------------------------------|
```

Comment: Wikipedia also has information about modern egg sizes for the U.S., Canada, Europe, and Australia (with additional information about egg sizes in Western Australia, New Zealand, and "traditional sizes") here: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_%28food%29#Chicken_egg_sizes".

Comment: I think those tables would be better as actual text/tables than images.

Comment: @hobodave, thanks for converting my tables to text!

Answer (score 0):

The first row reports the American size, and the other one reports the European size.

`|------------------------------------------------------|`
`| Jumbo --| X-Large | Large -| Medium | Small | Peewee |`
`|---------|---------|--------|--------|-------|--------|`
`| V. Large| Large --| Medium | Medium | Small | Small -|`
`|------------------------------------------------------|`