# What's the US equivalent of double and single cream?

Tags: cream, language

I can find whipping cream, half and half, and even clotted cream where I'm staying in the US but not double or single cream, are these familiar terms or is there a US equivalent term?

Comment: Whoever answers this should update this wiki as well: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/60

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the UK, single cream is a milk product with at least 18% butterfat.  Double cream has 48% butterfat.  Neither are common in the US.

If you can find clotted cream, which is 55% fat, then there is a chance of making double cream at home by diluting it.  As some clotted creams have a cooked taste, there may be other solutions.

Comment: Was 5% fat for single cream a typo? Other answers I've found have said 18%. 5% isn't much more than whole milk, which is 4% fat.

Comment: @Jimothy is right. I fixed the answer (source http://bit.ly/1WUP4Uq). There is a cereal milk that runs at 5%, a tad creamier than US whole milk.

Comment: Light cream (single cream) is generally available only in New England and the Mid-Atlantic states. I've been all over the US and never found it anywhere else.

Answer (score 6):

In Canada, we have

- Half and Half (10%)
- Table Cream (18%)
- Whipping Cream (35%)

There's also a "Light" cream at about 6%, but that's a newer product.

So I've always taken Half and Half to be "Half cream", Table to be single (roughly 2 x 10%) and Whipping to be double (roughly 2 x 18%)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a link to the US specifications: [21 CFR PART 131—MILK AND CREAM](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?&node=pt21.2.131)

From there:

- Light Cream (18% or more fat)
- Heavy Cream (36% or more)
- Dry Cream (*I've never heard of it*, 40% or more)

From the percentages provided by Papin's answer, it looks like:

- U.S. Light Cream is likely Single Cream equivalent
- Some U.S. Heavy Creams may be close to Double Cream
- U.S. Dry Cream, if you can find it, is something to consider

**Update**, I also learned:

- Looking at *fat content* alone is not enough to compare US v. UK creams. Pasteurization practices are also a large factor. Apparently most (*or all?*) U.S. heavy cream is processed using Ultra-high temperature processing (UHT), and UHT reportedly yields less flavorful heavy cream than UK double cream.
- I read Double Cream, when used as a whipping cream, can be problematic. Apparently, it's higher fat content makes it prone to *over-whipping* if you don't pay close attention.

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly a direct answer, but in terms of practicalities, I tend to use Darigold Classic 36% Heavy Whipping Cream as a substitute for double cream in recipes. and I've had a lot of success, where the cream was intended for richness as opposed to thickness.

Answer (score 2):

Manufacturing cream would be the closest substitute for double cream. It is heavy cream with a minimum of 40% butterfat and is available at Costco and Smart and Final. Sometimes manufacturing cream is labeled 'heavy cream' but the label will say 40% butterfat.

Comment: USA only, not available in Canada sadly.