# What is caster/castor sugar?

Tags: sugar

I've got a Meringue recipe that calls for castor sugar.

Is that different than powdered sugar?

Comment: It's "castor sugar", known as superfine or bar sugar in the US.

Comment: @hobodave: Thanks! (btw: It is spelled "caster" in my recipe.)

Comment: Ah! Apparently it goes both ways. I was just going by prior site precedent.

Comment: I decided against closing as duplicate. It seems an annoying hoop to jump through for any future people coming across the question. I'll just answer it and reference the wiki.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Castor (caster) sugar is known as superfine, or bar sugar in the US. It's not the same as powdered sugar which is even finer, has been mechanically pulverized, and is often mixed with starch to prevent clumping.

According to [Ochef](http://www.ochef.com/580.htm) you can make it with regular granulated sugar in your food processor for two minutes, but let the sugar dust settle before opening.

> **See Also:**
>   [Translating cooking terms between US / UK / AU / CA](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/60)

Answer (score 2):

Hobodave has answered this well - as an English person I can answer very simply. Caster sugar (UK spelling!) is, as Hobodave says, known as superfine sugar in the US. Powdered sugar is known as icing sugar in the UK.

Comment: does 'icing sugar' include cornstarch (US; UK : cornflour) in it ?

Comment: @Joe: We use all three terms interchangeably here (we prefer *confectioner's sugar*) and the answer is yes.  See [powdered sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confectioner%27s_sugar) on Wikipedia or this [ochef question](http://www.ochef.com/663.htm).