# What is the name for a dish similar to chili but with no chili peppers or related spices and some very non-chili ingredients?

Tags: classification

I made something the other day and I'm not sure what you'd call it.  I softened some onions, celery, carrot, and garlic in olive oil;  browned some ground venison in with the veggies and oil; added some beans, chicken stock, diced tomato, and tomato paste; let cook for a bit; threw in some spinach and let cook to wilt; cubed some stale rolls and threw them in there too.

It struck me as somewhat similar to a chili but has no chili peppers or related spices and some other things you normally wouldn't find in chili.  What would you call it?

Comment: See also: [stew vs casserole](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/is-there-a-difference-between-stew-and-casserole) and [soup vs stew](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/20958/difference-between-soup-and-stew).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call that a stew or a soup depending on how "brothy" it is.

Comment: There's little to no liquid remaining.  Would it still classify as a stew?

Comment: Yeah, some people consider things stew even when they are quite unbrothy.  Or you could just call it a "braise".