# What is a casserole (vessel)?

Tags: language, pot, casserole

Maybe it's because I'm German speaking, but I'm utterly confused by the concept of the concept of a Casserole.

When I enter "Kasserolle" in the [German Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=casserole) I on the one side get dishes that look like that they could get put into the oven. But on the other side I get pots which have a long grip. In my family we used to call them "milk pots".

Are these milk pots also supposed to be put into the oven? I've never seen anybody put pots like these into the oven, but doesn't the word "casserole" usually imply recipes that require an oven? I am utterly confused by the concept of "casserole".

Why does it seem to imply two different kinds of dishes ("milk pots" and dishes I'd use to make a lasagne)?

Comment: Could you add a link to an actual item that looks like a milk pot but says it is a "Kasserolle"? I am not sure what you mean by "But on the other side".

Comment: https://www.gourmet-web.de/bilder/produkte/gross/Professionelle-Edelstahl-Kasserolle.jpg. For example this one.

Comment: @user3169 I think op means "on one hand/on the other hand".

Comment: @Catija Ah yes sorry, Of course I meant "on the other hand"

Comment: If you check the definitions, there does not seem to be a one-to-one correspondence between [*Kasserolle*](http://en.langenscheidt.com/german-english/kasserolle) and [*casserole*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/casserole). Kasserolle seems to have a broader usage as to what kind of cookware it refers to.

Answer (score 4):

This is from a UK perspective.  A casserole dish is generally round or oval, almost always has a lid, and can go in the oven. It may be made of a variety of materials.

The use that earns the name is cooking dishes consisting of ingredients cut up and in a liquid sauce/gravy, without a topping except possibly dumplings. The terms *casserole* and *stew* have a lot in common. The dishes may be used for other things as well.

Some can also be used on top of the stove (metal ones, a few special ceramic examples). This is handy for browning ingredients before adding the liquid. There's obvious overlap with a (fairly large) saucepan, but unlike casserole dishes saucepans may have long handles, which might not be suitable for oven use either because of size or material.

A milk *pan* (not *pot*) is a small saucepan with a long handle, usually with a lid, and sometimes with a spout. In a set of saucepans it would be the smallest.

Comment: @paparazzi "a lot in common". I think we've already had a question about the difference; if not maybe we should. It might well be yet another US/UK difference in terminology but the variation within each country may be greater.

Comment: Here's the previous discussion about terminology http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/is-there-a-difference-between-stew-and-casserole

Answer (score 1):

In the US casserole is a general term for a slowly baked dish with multiple ingrediants. I would call a lasagne a type of casserole.

The typical dish is a baking dish.

[image: baking dish]

Handles are not required but common.  Useful for other slowly baked items such as meat.

Comment: The dish is often actually called a "casserole", which is, I believe, what this question is asking about. I've seen many recipes that call for a "five-quart casserole". Like on the Target website [here](http://www.target.com/p/rachael-ray-cucina-oval-casserole-blue-3-5-qt/-/A-16771401)

Comment: Funnily enough unlike in your answer in the UK a lasagne dish wouldn't be called a casserole dish. Casserole dishes in en-gb are usually round or oval and almost always have a lid. But then in UK usage a casserole would be stirrable unlike a lasagne

Comment: @ChrisH In the US an Italian would not call it casserole.

Comment: @Catija And it is often called a baking dish.     http://www.crateandbarrel.com/potluck-lasagna-red-baking-dish/s379125

Comment: But the question isn't about the food... It's about the confusion between a baking dish and a milk pot, both of which are referred to as a "Kasserolle"... your answer doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @Catija It does mention food.  The point is casserole is a variety of foods and will have a variety of dishes that go by a variety of names.   A commonality slow baked.