# What are powdered sugar cubes?

Tags: sugar, cubes

Is the sugar yielded from sugar cubes considered a kind of sugar? If so, what is it called? Confectionery sugar?

Comment: hmm. cubiquitous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never seen, heard of, or found any reference to powdered sugar cubes. Sugar cubes are made with white granulated sugar. They can also be colored or flavored, but the typical cubes found at the market are plain white sugar.

Powdered sugar is also known as confectioner's sugar and is used for frostings, dusting the tops of cakes & funnel cakes, etc. Powdered sugar can be made by blending or processing granulated sugar.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I meant by the question, was, what is yielded from blending or processing sugar cubes? What is it called? Is it a type of sugar?

Comment: @Gigili I think this answer covers it.  The sugar is just granulated sugar pressed into a cube shape.  If you break the shape down, you've just got granulated sugar again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @logophobe. But what I read [here](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/is-granulated-sugar-american-the-same-as-caster-sugar-uk) it somehow different from what you are saying. granulated sugar is the everyday table sugar but what I get from grinding sugar cubes is a lot finer than that, is it called caster sugar? I'd use the powder in baking but I don't know whether to use it when the recipe calls for granulated sugar or caster sugar or icing sugar or what?!

Comment: @Gigili It depends how you're breaking the cubes down - if using a food processor, you're also partially pulverizing the granules, and you'll wind up with something closer to caster or superfine sugar.  If your recipe calls for a particular type of sugar, you're best off buying it rather than trying to produce it from cubes.