# Does the thickness of a cake affect the baking time?

Tags: cake, mold

I am very new to baking, so this may be a bit of an obvious question, but:
My daughter wants an airplane shaped chocolate cake for her birthday. I have seen various ideas where you bake a cake, then cut it into pieces and assemble them.
But I was thinking, could I make an airplane-shaped mold, put the mixture in, and bake it whole?
Would I have a problem with the thin parts like the tail & wings being overdone while the middle of the fuselage is still uncooked?
Would there be any other issues I need to be aware of?
Cheers!

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/27516/67

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would have a problem whereby thinner parts would cook quicker than thicker ones. You are much better off cooking uniform cakes (sheet cakes are ideal) and cutting them to shape.

Comment: Agreed ... and depending on the type of plane being made, it might be better to use cake for the body, and cookies for the tail fins.   If it's a large plane with low wings, then just use a sheet cake for wings ... if it's something like a piper cub, use cardboard or cookie (or cookie supported by cardboard)