# Doubling a red velvet cake recipe

Tags: cake

I have made 4 times the recipe in order to make a half sheet cake. Do I lower the degrees and bake time?

Comment: Your title says double, your text says 4 times, which is it? Are you making one big cake or 4 smaller ones?

Comment: A half sheet pan is 18" by 13" (46 by 33 cm), is that the size you're making? Sheet pans are thin, with a 1" (2.5 cm) raised lip. This is jelly roll territory, it would either make a very thin cake or you can cut it make a many layered cake, which would make sense with a red velvet cake. Can you explain exactly what you're doing and post your quantities? 4X makes no sense, 2X maybe, depending upon your recipe.

Comment: I'm confused. The above comment and the answers refer to using a sheet pan. I don't see anywhere in the question where the OP says she is using a sheet pan. She says she is making a sheet cake. Sheet cake pans typically range from 2" to 4" deep.

Answer (score 2):

If you're making the same thickness of cake, and it's a relatively thin cake (suggested by the fact that you're using a sheet pan), you typically do not need to change the time and temperature.  So if you've doubled the recipe *and* doubled the area of the pan, you don't need to make any changes.

A larger area cake will rise more as there won't be as much edge that will set before the rest has risen.

If it's a thicker cake (the batter is more than 1/2" / 1.25 cm deep before baking), you'll want to turn down the temperature and bake for a longer time.  If the batter is an inch or more deep, you may want to consider [cooling strips and/or a heating core](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/27516/67).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a highly rated recipe for a [Red Velvet Cake](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/ree-drummond/red-velvet-sheet-cake-with-classic-red-velvet-frosting-recipe.html) in a sheet pan by Lee Drummond.

If you're in fact using a sheet pan, compare the quantities of your ingredients to hers. I wouldn't go any bigger in a sheet pan, or it will overflow. I know from experience, that makes a big mess.

She uses:

- 2 1/2 cups cake flour
- 1teaspoon salt
- 1 cup buttermilk
- 1 teaspoon vanilla extract
- 1 teaspoon baking soda
- 2 whole eggs
- 1 1/2 teaspoons vinegar
- 1 1/2 teaspoons cocoa powder
- 1 1/2 fluid ounces red food coloring
- 1 cup shortening
- 1 3/4 cup granulated sugar

Make sure your ingredient quantites are in line with that.

She goes on to bake for 20 minutes at 350F (178C).