# Why would the exterior of a cake cook and not the interior?

Tags: baking, cake

I attempted to make the blueberry corn cake from "All About Cake" by Christina Tosi, and for both layers, the top of the cake got rock solid and started to collapse down, but the inside of the cake was goo - barely cooked. I'm pretty sure I followed the recipe, and have never seen anything like this happen to a cake before. Fellow baker family members are stumped - any ideas what might have happened?

Comment: Could you have had the oven on a grill setting rather than convection oven setting? Or omitted to pre-heat the oven?

Comment: Sounds like the oven temperature might have been too high

Comment: If it's a foam based cake- angel or chiffon- this will happen if not baked in a tube pan. The batter itself is too insulative.

Comment: It's not just foam cakes ... baking it in too large of a pan will do this, too : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/27516/67

Answer (score 1):

May be the temperature of the oven was too high so the outer part got cooked too quickly leaving the inner cake raw.

Answer (score 0):

Your oven is likely too hot, or you're starting with a cold batter. Make sure to start with a batter closer to room temperature and try reducing the oven temperature.

Most ovens have hot spots or poor calibration, if you continue to have trouble pick up an over thermometer and check to see what the real temperature is at various spots.