# What is wrong with my icing?

Tags: cake, icing

I have read recipes that says mix half cup butter and 1.5 times the icing sugar and beat, add some milk, not more than 2-3 spoons. I have been beating it for last 30 minutes and tasted it, the sugar is still not dissolved in the cream, am I doing some thing wrong?

Comment: Did you use the correct sugar?  Icing sugar is the one like baby powder.

Comment: hmm...its not finely powdered but still quite powdered, the pack says icing sugar and am a n00b chef all excited after acquiring a new microwave oven :(

Comment: It should be like dust.  There shouldn't be any discernible grains.  If you want to try again, run it in small batches in a blender (or rotary coffee/spice grinder) to grind it down as fine as you can.

Comment: Chris, though its not dust but its not crystal either, its more like fine sand, I and my wife are taking turns to beat it, it will be 1 am soon and I asked this 1 question 35 minutes ago, we are wasting a Friday evening with wrong ingredient for cake :P

Comment: That sounds like "fruit sugar" or superfine.  Icing sugar is like dust, and it dissolves instantly.  I think you should give up.  It won't dissolve.  Spread it on your breakfast toast with a bit of cinnamon to use it up.

Comment: :-( ok, I have already baked the cake, will store it in the fridge, will get icing sugar tomorrow, thankfully there is a departmental store at a stone's throw from my apartment, but thanks for your advice. I wish I could choose your comment as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on comments to the original question:

It sounds like you used the wrong type of sugar.  Icing sugar is also referred to as [powdered sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powdered_sugar) or confectioner's sugar.  From your description, it sounds like you used what we call (in Canada) superfine or fruit sugar (sugar for sprinkling on fruit, not from fruit).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using confectioner's sugar?  Usually you start with about 1 cup then beat in 1/2 stick of butter and gradually add your whole milk or cream slowly to the consistency your looking for. Some people like it fluffier than others

Comment: ...now what is a onfectioner's sugar? Now I have a box of sugar that clearly says icing sugar and its different brand and is costlier than what I used earlier

Comment: @Kumar : 'confectioner's sugar' is what it's labeled as in the U.S. -- in most areas speaking British English, it's called 'icing sugar'.  see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca

Comment: Thanks! +1 You pointed me to conversion table, engineers love conversion tables :P