# What does it mean for something to be broiled?

Tags: language

More specifically, what is the difference between broiling and boiling?

Comment: Answered on http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca-nz

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't compare at all - broiling is the US term for what is called grilling in UK. The heat source is above the food.

In the US, a "grill" is used to mean a "gas powered barbeque", as the Brits would say.  The heat source is below the food.

Comment: A "broiler" (*i.e.*, a kitchen appliance specifically designed for applying intense heat from above) is often also called a "[salamander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grilling#Salamander)", especially in professional kitchens.

Comment: Of course, a "grill" can also be charcoal powered rather than gas.

Comment: I'd suggest a different term than "barbeque" in the US.  Of course, we do call grills "barbeques", but there is also another noun, verb, and adjective of the same word, which usually means something quite different here.  My talks with people from other countries (most notably Brits and Aussies) tend to have a hard time wrapping their head around the various US uses of the word "barbeque" as it tends to just be a word for general grilling where ever they're from.

Comment: @Phoenix what are you talking about? "I'd suggest a different term than "barbeque" in the US. Of course, we do call grills "barbeques", but there is also another noun, verb, and adjective of the same word, which usually means something quite different here"  What is that noun verb and adjective?

Comment: @barlop: BBQ in the American South means slow-cooked in a smoker. Which is quite different than the grill meaning of BBQ (fast-cooked over a fire)

Comment: Well, Barbeque has quite a few uses (and it's not just in the South).  It's kind of a unique food, can't really say regional dish but a gradated one (it's all over the US, but a neighboring town's is usually different but similar style than anothers', and the farther you get from one town towards another, the more different it is, like a color gradient).  It almost always has one thing in common:  Pork being slow cooked over many hours (not necessarily in a smoker) until the meat is tender enough to simply fall off the bone at the slightest touch, and the sauce, which is what really changes.

Comment: (also some places use Beef, ugh) Some places use a vinegar based sauce (which is the right way!), some use tomato based sauce, some use a dry rub, etc. etc. etc. and every place has it's own ingredients that go into the sauce.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbecue_in_the_United_States     http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbecue#Styles