# What is the difference between Grills, Barbecues, Broiling e.t.c.?

Tags: grilling, barbecue, broiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Translating cooking terms between US / UK / AU / CA / NZ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca-nz)

What is the difference between Grills, Barbecues, Broiling e.t.c.?

Note: I plan to post my own answer, but you're welcome to post yours.

Comment: Maybe http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca-nz can help you.

Comment: Or http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/14312/what-does-it-mean-for-something-to-be-broiled as well.

Comment: What do you imagine *e.t.c.* stands for?

Comment: @TRiG Endless Terminological Confusion?

Answer (score 2):

As Mien pointed out in the comments, these terms can vary based on where you are from. My answer is based on the U.S. version of the terms.

**Grilling**: To cook with direct exposure to heat, usually from *below*.

**Broiling**: To cook with direct exposure to heat, usually from *above*.

**BBQing**: To cook with indirect heat using wood in order to add a smoke flavor.

In many parts of the U.S. grilling and BBQing are used synonymously, in which it mostly implies grilling meat outdoors, although, as you can see by the definitions above, that isn't entirely accurate.

Answer (score -1):

Using Ryan's definitions for clarity -

Grilling: To cook with direct exposure to heat, usually from below.

Broiling: To cook with direct exposure to heat, usually from above.

BBQing: To cook with indirect heat using wood in order to add a smoke flavor.

I have to make the point that broiling can be done with electricity, whereas grilling is by definition by something burning (in my case it is usually lighter fluid).

If you power your grill with charcoal, you can get that smoky flavour by adding woodchips into the fuel - to my mind, that is barbequeing, even if the heating is direct.