# What is the difference between preserves and conserves?

Tags: language, ingredient-selection

I will start off by admitting that I do see technical definitions [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15175/whats-the-difference-between-jam-jelly-and-preserves/57423#57423), but I did not actually learn that there was such a thing as conserves until today.  I am used to putting jelly, or jam or preserves on my toast in the morning, but apparently I can also put conserves on toast as well.  So what is the difference then between the two and how would a cook use them differently?  Is it a regional thing, or are there times one would choose one over the other?  Does one complement certain foods better than the other?

Comment: I've never heard them called "Conserves" but the definition you linked to makes them sound more like mincemeat (or possibly even a chutney?)

Comment: See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/3027/67

Comment: That is another good description thanks.  I notice it is on the translate terms between countries question, but that particular answer does not do that.  So where is conserve popular and sold?  I imagine I would have a hard time getting it in the US if I were looking for conserve?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is conserves are boiled down until they reach a consistency that can heap on a spoon. Preserves generally are not boiled down, and are chunky.