# Preserving leftover double cream

Tags: food-preservation, cream

I've got about 200ml of Double Cream (48% butterfat [apparently](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca-nz)) that I don't think i'll use before it goes off.

What simple (~5 minute) things can you make with cream so that it can be frozen?

---

At the moment I'm thinking along the lines of chocolate or toffee sauces.

Comment: Probably too obvious, but: Ice cream?

Comment: @rumtscho Can you make Ice Cream in 5 minutes?

Comment: Philadelphia style ice cream is made without cooking a custard. Mix cream and milk, cook up the sugar and vanilla in a very small part of the mix, combine, chill, freeze. Because of the chill, you have to wait longer than 5 minutes before freezing, but the actual work is less than 5 minutes.

Comment: nice. Will consider this next time (when I've got more cream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, above 40% fat, you can just freeze the cream itself. It wont whip as high, if you defrost it and whip it later, but it'll still taste good. Below 40% the results aren't as good.

Answer (score 1):

Caramel sauce.  It takes sugar, water, cream, a pinch of salt, and a tsp or so of lemon juice. Optionally, you can throw in a couple TBSP of rum, tequila, or brandy to enrich the flavor.

As far as I know, it'll freeze indefinitely, and it'll keep for MONTHS in the fridge.

Comment: If I could accept this answer as well I would. But I went with just freezing it.  I think I'll end up making a Caramel (or toffee) sauce with it eventually. Thanks :)