# What do you call eggs prepared with a broken yolk, in a skillet, with no char?

Tags: eggs, yolk

What do you call eggs prepared with a broken yolk, in a skillet, with no char?
I crack 2 eggs into a saute skillet & break both yolks, cover with a lid & wait a couple minutes with medium heat, then flip them over & turn off heat for 1 more minute. I would like a quick easy description so I can order easily in restaurants

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/16990/67

Answer (score 5):

Where I come from, that would be called 'over hard.'

As a reference, the others would be over-easy (runny yolk), over-medium (soft, slightly runny), and the over-hard would be cooked solid.

Chefs will often break the yolk on an over-hard order, before flipping the egg, if it's not already broken.

Comment: The method I usually use is basically start by making over medium but break the yolk after flipping. That way you still end up with the aesthetic over an over-_whatever_ egg.

Comment: Chefs breaks the yoke before flipping? If you order an over easy you would expect a broken yoke?

Comment: @Dorothy to clarify, the method that I described was from when I _was a chef_. I would not break a yolk before I flipped the egg.