# What can I do to " fresh cream" to substitute "double cream"?

Tags: substitutions, cream

Here in NZ you can buy "cream". It does not even say "single" or "double" or "whipping". I do know however it can be whipped in to a nice thick cream. Lots of recipes/sauces call for "double cream" what is the difference and how can I make cream into "double" cream or is their anything else I can add that will result in the same taste ?

Comment: See also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca-nz

Comment: @ Jefromi, did not know that page existed till now, thanks for that its very useful,good page for users to keep updating too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In NZ normal pure cream is close enough to "double cream" in performance, it's around 35% to 40% fat. By general global definition it should be called "heavy cream"

NZ cream is pure skimmed cream from fresh milk, and does not need thickening or other processing to produce excellent results as a whipped product, or for a thick cream additive in sauces or fillings

Cream can get a little seasonal just after calving time (Aug), but in general it's just perfect

The export variety is often labelled "Culinary Cream" and is 38% fat or higher. This is what many people around the world would consider NZ cream (other than NZ butter or AMF)

If you want closer to 50% fat cream, ask your local farmers for some raw milk and skim out the lumps of fat from that. Let the milk settle overnight and skim the cream from that. Then gently heat the fat lumps to melt and carefully mix into the skimmed cream. Not for the faint of heart!

NZ "Thickened cream" or "Mascarpone cream" is standard pure cream with a thickener like E1442 added, you can [make your own too](http://frugalkiwi.co.nz/2009/09/making-mascarpone/)

Comment: Thanks TFD, just the info I was looking for, good to have another NZ person around for these types of questions but I do think I'll keep buying and using as is, the farmer idea is interesting but think I just not tough enough !

Comment: @TFDvalid point,will bear in mind for future reference.