# Does a GRILL in a UK recipe refer to a BROILER in US?

Tags: broiling

In a recipe from the UK it says to turn the GRILL to high and place food on baking sheet as close to grill as possible. This sounds like a Broiler in US. Am i correct?

Comment: There's a long thread of [translation of cooking terms](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/4590) which is a useful reference for this and related questions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a grill in the UK is essentially the same thing as a top broiler. In the UK, and most of western Europe, ovens are electric and have no separate drawer - the grill is a heating element at the top of the oven. Ovens come with a tray that slots in at the top, similar to a broiler pan.

Comment: This answer is correct in stating that a grill in the UK is the same as a broiler, but not that most UK homes don't have a separate grill. It is in fact much more common in the majority of homes to have a separate grill, in modern ovens this is often a combined oven and grill section (which is smaller than the main oven), and some ovens also have a grill in the main oven (in addition to the separate smaller grill/oven). 

I am British and in my 40s, and I can only think of one oven I've ever noticed in any home which didn't have a separate grill.