# Can Of Tomato Soup in England

Tags: measurements, food-identification

I’m using a recipe that includes a can of tomato soup but i don’t know how much to use. I can’t find cans of it because I use cardboard boxes for it.
How much is in a can of tomato soup in milliliters or cups?

Comment: Do you mean you are using a US recipe in England, or the other way around?

Comment: from a quick google, a regular can of campbell soup concentrate is about 284 ml

Comment: Just to clarify, tomato sauce or tomato soup?

Comment: Could you post the entire recipe @Niamh?

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/54543/67

Comment: It won't quite help for this specific question, but for older recipes that specify a can number, as opposed to just assuming that all food of one type comes in a specific sized can, [I've transcribed a list](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/111033/67)

Answer (score 2):

I would expect a British recipe to specify whether the soup is condensed (usually Campbell's brand) or ready to eat (after heating), examples are Heinz, Baxter's or any of the many supermarket own brands. So you need to specify what the recipe calls for. If it's condensed, the tins contain 295ml of the concentrate. The other sort comes in several sizes, but if a British recipe calls for "a can" I'd say it's likely to be 400ml, unless otherwise specified.