# Baking apple roses in oven in France, which mark should I choose?

Tags: oven, apples, puff-pastry

I'm baking some apple roses as described here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rGrwvEjZIQ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKOla0-aW5o. Basically, it's apple-packed puff pastry plus some other ingredients, baked in the oven.

In both of the recipes, they instruct to set the oven to 400 degree F (=200 degree C approx.) I'm in France and using their oven, I set the temperature to 200 degree C and chose the mark "flans/tartes", set the roses for 42 minutes. They got burnt quite a bit. What mark should I choose? I see that there's also a
"poissons/pâtisseries" mark, should I choose that instead? Or, should I just lower the temperature?

Comment: Excuse me if it is quicker for me to ask then watch some video: Is this using homemade or storebought puff pastry? If storebought, I would start with whatever the instructions on the pastry suggest, and adjust from there. You could always make a couple, put them in the fridge unbaked, and then bake them one by one at different temperatures/oven rails/modes (convection vs still oven will matter here). Also try covering them with tinfoil for a part of the baking time, so they can bake while not browning/drying out as much.

Comment: This is store-bought. Thanks for your comment, but my problem is with the oven being French though.

Comment: Do french ovens come with any feature that keeps you from doing trial runs? ;) I would suggest double checking that you do not have convection on.

Comment: if they're numbered like the British gas marks, see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/27517/67