# What is a Tin of Tomatoes?

Tags: measurements

My recipe calls for a small tin of tomatoes plus another tin of tomatoes.
Is a small tin of tomatoes equal to a 14 1/2 oz size can of tomatoes and the tin of tomatoes equal to the 28 oz size can or is the tin of tomatoes equal to a 14 1/2 oz can size and the small tin equal to something along the size of a tomato sauce can?

Comment: I think you're right in that the older question should've been tagged with 'measurements'.  I've fixed the other one.  Also see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/67

Comment: A this is essentially a guesswork, some more clues you can provide are 1) Which country the recipe comes from? 2) what is the recipe doing with the small can? i.e. is it added together with the large can or used separately?

Answer (score 0):

If it says "tomatoes", I would think that your first guess is correct. I have not seen or heard "tomatoes" being sold in cans smaller than 14 oz, at least in US. The only tomato products in smaller cans are tomato sauce/paste.