# What type of flour is "wheat flour" in the UK?

Tags: flour, language

I want to replicate an American recipe of [Banana Chocolate Chip Muffins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1WwYWUVoc_o&index=2&list=PLGbOfKEt499ldKVuNhuwciyuZY6r7H8Qn). It requires 1 cup of wheat flour.

What type of flour would that be in the UK shops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is called wholemeal flour.

Here's a quick US to UK baking translation guide. US on the left, UK on the right:

- All-purpose flour = plain flour
- bread flour  =  strong flour (both have extra gluten)
- whole wheat flour = wholemeal flour
- 1 stick of butter is 113g (get a scale, trust me)
- 1 large egg = 1 medium egg

Comment: doh.  I had the rest, but was missing 'wholemeal' in the [list of translations](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/67)

Comment: Regional differences regarding soft and hard wheat used for various flour grades can still yield unexpected results...