# How do you convert British recipes to American measurements?

Tags: measurements

How do you convert British recipes to American measurements?

Comment: "British?" Do you mean gramms etc. ounces? Honestly, you do it like we Europeans use American recipes with cups and oz. : look up the conversion (table, formula, online tool) and do the math.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're dealing with British Imperial measurements (as opposed to metric).

The main 'gotchas' are cups/pints/quarts, and tablespoons:

```
US cup   = 8 fl.oz.  British cup   = 10 fl.oz
US pint  = 16 fl.oz  British pint  = 20 fl.oz
US quart = 32 fl.oz  British quart = 40 fl.oz

US tablespoon = 14.2 mL ; British tablespoon = 17.7 mL
```

Also see [Translating cooking terms between US / UK / AU / CA / NZ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/67) .

Comment: and there's also the "metric cup" (8.45 fl.oz; 250mL).  And the infamous 'dessert spoon' (9.5mL)

Comment: not to mention that a 15ml tablespoon isn't a tables-poon but a dessert-spoon. Though for recipes this is now always taken to be ~15ml, older  cookbooks will mean ~25ml when they use the term "table-spoon"