# Australian Thickened Cream

Tags: cream

Can anyone tell me the UK equivalent of Australian Thickened Cream. Not sure if it's what we call Single or Double cream. Thank you

Comment: Not a straightforward translation possible. See e.g. https://www.nowtolove.com.au/how-to/expert-qa/the-beginners-guide-to-cream-15816 and https://www.dairygoodness.ca/cream/cream-glossary. So you will have us to tell us what you want to use it for. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Based on Jan's links, it looks like it's 35% fat, while the UK single & double creams are 18% and 46%.  I'll go update https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/67

Answer (score 3):

Thickened cream is cream that has a thickener in it with a minimum fat content of 35% - it whips well. I would look for something like this; I've seen cream called whipping cream which I would assume is the same, with the added thickener. If you can't find that the most similar cream is double cream - it's the most versatile  - it's got a higher fat content of about 50%, it doesn't have a thickener, but you can whip it.