# Are the terms self-rising flour and baking powder different in the US and UK?

Tags: baking, flour, language, cultural-difference

I made Mary Berry’s Cherry cake, which called for 275 g of self-rising flour and 2 tsp of baking powder, in an 8-inch pan. Went all over the oven. Are these ingredients different in the US?

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is nope. The UK and USA are in agreement on this one. Self-rising flour and baking powder are the same on both sides of the pond. See also [Translating cooking terms between US / UK / AU / CA / NZ](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca-nz)

Note: I thought that two tsp of baking powder was an odd thing to see in a recipe that uses self-rising flour so I looked up a Mary Berry cherry cake recipe. The BBC published a [recipe on their website](https://www.bbc.com/food/recipes/marys_cherry_cake_17869) and it doesn't call for baking powder. Are you sure your recipe didn't say "OR"?

Comment: There is one difference: we call it "self-r**a**ising"! +1

Comment: There are two differences - **there is no salt in UK self-raising flour.**

Answer (score 3):

The cherry cake in *More Fast Cakes* (1985) has 175g SR flour and 1tsp baking powder, and the "English cherry cake" in *Mary Berry's Ultimate Cake Book* (1994 reprinted 2003) has 275g and 2tsp. Recipes with both aren't unknown but this seems like a lot of extra baking powder. It must be meant to rise a lot

Apart from children's books most of the cakes I make are from her recipes and they seems reliable.

I assume you used the *deep* cake tin specified. I can't instantly lay my hands on mine but it's about 4" deep.

How accurate is your oven temperature? A recipe like this would rise fast, and may be prone to over rising then dropping if cooked too fast. The later recipe cooks rather cool at 160C/325F,and that's without a fan.

Comment: Wow, a 4" deep tin, I don't think I have ever seen one that size, except for gugelhupf. This is a very important point you are making, and deserves attention.

Comment: No, the pan was the problem. Didn’t realize deep would mean DEEP. Do you think an angel food pan would work for this?

Comment: It might work. I've never had one (they're not common here) but the ones on amazon look good and deep. I reckon a normal 8" tin would be about 2.5" deep, so specifying "deep" says quite a bit more than that, to me. But with the angel food pan you lose a bit of volume in the middle