# Thicken stew/sauce twice with flour

Tags: thickening

When making a stew, I forgot to add flour before the liquid. To thicken the stew, I added some slurry (flour + cold water). However, it was not enough. I would add more slurry, but I found [this](https://www.bitchinfrommelanieskitchen.com/2012/07/-need-to-thicken-food-in-a-hurry-make-a-slurry-.html) website (2012) that says

> If you've prepared a dish that started out with a roux and you feel it needs a slurry at the end for additional thickening:  use cornstarch or arrowroot to prepare the slurry.  Why?  Because a chemical reaction occurs that will prevent the same starch used twice to thicken it any further.

I could find not any other sources supporting or opposing this claim, so I'll ask here:

Can I thicken a sauce/stew twice with flour (roux+slurry or slurry+slurry)?

Comment: You don't need flour for the thickening (and it can leave a bit of a raw flour flavor if you add too much).   I shred a potato into the hot stew, and it'll dissolve into the liquid but release its starch.  Instant potato flakes also work well.

Comment: This initially sounded like complete nonsense to me (an Australian), because in Australia Corn Flour is normally made of Wheat; and so would be the same starch.
Then I checked https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca-nz and saw that in the other listed countries it is infact made of various parts of the corn.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A reaction that prevents starch from the same plant thickening if you add it later instead of all at the same time seems very unlikely. And anyway, a roux could be made with non-wheat flour even though it's not traditional - what do they think would happen then? Or if you make a roux on another pan and add that. I can confirm that works.

There is a good reason not to add a slurry late in cooking - the raw flour flavour it imparts. That's why I'd use cornflour (corn starch) for late thickening.

Comment: I completely agree, the chemical reaction thing is complete hooey.

Comment: If you don't have cornstarch handy you could cook the slurry in a separate pan before adding it to the pot to cut down on the raw flavour.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to thicken a stew at the end of the cooking process, I've found that the best option is to use a buerre manie. Mix together equal parts flour and room-temperature (not melted) butter, and whisk that into your stew.