# Beating eggs for brownie

Tags: baking, eggs, language, brownies

[This](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81znfbxKg2L.jpg) brownie recipe (from [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1647221811) book) calls for *eggs, beaten*. I'm not entirely familiar with US recipes. What does it mean that the eggs have to be beaten? Is it sufficient to do this lightly with a fork or maybe they'd be better beaten using food processor?

Comment: And do you mind if I ask where you’re from?  Obviously not the US, but if you’re from an English speaking country, I should add this to https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/67

Comment: Oops.  Thought I had another comment — beaten eggs are like the mixing you would do in making ‘scrambled eggs’.  ‘Lightly beaten’ does not need to be homogenous (just yolks broken and a few seconds with a fork), and some recipes that need to denature proteins will instruct you to ‘beat until lemony yellow’ (which doesn’t work so well for eggs from Japan where the yolks might start that color)

Comment: @Joe thanks for your comments, I am actually from non-English-speaking European country. The one about degrees of egg-beating will probably be useful in future recipes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The eggs should be beaten until roughly homogeneous; that is, there should be no "pieces" of unmixed egg white left. (If left in, those pieces would cook and harden, leaving you with, essentially, pieces of boiled egg in your brownies.) With some eggs there will be small strings of connective tissue from the egg that tend to float to the surface and appear as (slightly lumpy) bits of the white; these may be picked out with a fork, but they're unlikely to be noticeable in brownies.

Assuming you're adept with a fork, beating an egg or two shouldn't take more than 60 seconds.

BTW: In this recipe, there's no fundamental reason to beat the eggs before you add them to anything else. As long as they're thoroughly mixed in before you add the flour and other dry ingredients, you'll be fine.