# What's the difference between British and American edition of McGee's "On Food and Cooking"?

Tags: cookbook, cultural-difference

It looks like there are two versions of the same book. British "McGee on Food and Cooking: An Encyclopedia of Kitchen Science, History and Culture", published on November 8th 2004 and American "On Food and Cooking: The Science and Lore of the Kitchen" published on November 16th 2004, written by Harold McGee.

What's the difference between these two? [Harold's webpage](https://curiouscook.typepad.com/site/on-food-and-cooking.html) does not mention the existence of the British version.

Comment: Go to the source.  Ask him on Twitter:  https://twitter.com/Harold_McGee. I bet he would reply to you.

Comment: It might be localized as food terms are different in the US and UK: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/67