# How to convert a cup to SI units?

Tags: conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert between the various measurements?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/76/how-do-i-convert-between-the-various-measurements)

How to convert a cup to [SI units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units)? In otherwords, how many liters (or deciliters) one cup is?

Comment: Strictly speaking of SI units, you should use cubic meters, which is too big for all days use (one cubic meter is one thousand liters).